# How to vertically center text in minipage environment?

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage, text, adjustbox

I'm writing my CV and the following one is a MWE regarding my question:

```
\documentclass[11 pt,oneside,a4paper,titlepage]{article}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{graphbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{adjustbox} % to a better alignement of text

\begin{document}

\adjustbox{valign=t}{%
\begin{minipage}{11.3cm}
    \vspace*{0.4cm}
          
    % Certificates
    \section*{CERTIFICATES}
   
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{2cm}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=0.8cm]{Logos/logo_PP.pdf}
    \end{center}
    \end{minipage}}
    \hfill \vline \hfill
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{9cm}
            \scriptsize 
            Microsoft Office Specialist PowerPoint 2016 (\textit{Microsoft, 2019})
    \end{minipage}}
    
    \vspace*{0.2cm}
   
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

I need to vertically align the text with respect to the vertical line, can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the height of a minipage (optional arguments), you can align the contents relative to the space itself.  The first argument [c] puts the baseline into the center of each minipage (regardless of the contents).  The third argument [c] centers the contents relative to the top and bottom.  You could also use [t] or [b] or [s] for the third argument without changing the `\hrule`s.

```
\documentclass[11 pt,oneside,a4paper,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{graphbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
%\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % not used

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{11.3cm}
    \vspace*{0.4cm}
          
    % Certificates
    \section*{CERTIFICATES}
    \hrule % show top of group
    \begin{minipage}[c]{2cm}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{example-image}%{Logos/logo_PP.pdf}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill \vline \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[c][0.8cm][c]{9cm}
            \scriptsize 
            Microsoft Office Specialist PowerPoint 2016 (\textit{Microsoft, 2019})
    \end{minipage}
    \hrule% show bottom of broup
    \vspace*{0.2cm}
   
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit lost in your MWE, so I rewrite document body code, which is to my opinion a bit more clear/logical.

**Edit:**
In the first answer version I overlooked vertical line between image and text. Not it is added. Also are `minipage`s replaced with `tabular` table:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % for vertical alignment of image

\begin{document}

% Certificates
\section*{CERTIFICATES}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{w{c}{20mm} | w{l}{98mm}}
\includegraphics[height=0.8cm, valign=m]{example-image-duck}%{Logos/logo_PP.pdf}
    &   \small
Microsoft Office Specialist PowerPoint 2016 (\textit{Microsoft, 2019})
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text box borders)